# sqlalchemy: create two databases in the same file

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create two separate databases in a single file using SQLAlchemy. Here's the code I have so far:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer, inspect
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_2'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


engine1 = create_engine('sqlite:///db1.db')
engine2 = create_engine('sqlite:///db2.db')
Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine1)
Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine2)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine1)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine2)

print(inspect(engine1).get_table_names())
# ['table_1', 'table_2']
print(inspect(engine2).get_table_names())
# ['table_1', 'table_2']
```

I want to create only Table1 in db1 and only Table2 in db2; however, I'm getting both tables in both databases.

Is there anyway to resolve this or do I need to create the databases in two separate files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't caused by trying to create the two databases in the same module. Rather, you are calling `create_all()` on the same metadata object that has mapped both of the tables. E.g.

```
print(Base.metadata.tables)
```

result:

```
dict_keys(['table_1', 'table_2'])
```

From the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#creating-and-dropping-database-tables) about `MetaData.create_all()`:

> This method will issue queries that first check for the existence of
>   each individual table, and if not found will issue the CREATE
>   statements...

Key point is it checks for the existence of *each* table. So here:

```
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine1)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine2)
```

... it first checks for both tables in the db referenced by `engine1`, doesn't find them and creates them. Then, it checks for both tables in the db referenced by `engine2`, doesn't find them, and creates them.

There's a couple of options.

Have different Base objects (i.e. a distinct MetaData instance) for each database:

```
Base1 = declarative_base()
Base2 = declarative_base()


class Table1(Base1):
    __tablename__ = 'table_1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Table2(Base2):
    __tablename__ = 'table_2'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

engine1 = create_engine('sqlite:///db1.db')
engine2 = create_engine('sqlite:///db2.db')
Base1.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine1)
Base2.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine2)
Base1.metadata.create_all(bind=engine1)
Base2.metadata.create_all(bind=engine2)

print(inspect(engine1).get_table_names())
# ['table_1']
print(inspect(engine2).get_table_names())
# ['table_2']
```

Or, selectively create the tables while binding to the desired engine:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_1'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_2'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


engine1 = create_engine('sqlite:///db1.db')
engine2 = create_engine('sqlite:///db2.db')
Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine1)
Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine2)
Base.metadata.tables['table_1'].create(bind=engine1)
Base.metadata.tables['table_2'].create(bind=engine2)

print(inspect(engine1).get_table_names())
# ['table_1']
print(inspect(engine2).get_table_names())
# ['table_2']
```

Comment: Awesome! Are there pros and cons for either approach?

Comment: TBH not really. Either way you need to make sure that you are querying through a session that is bound to the right engine for the model. I'd be interested to hear if you come across any limitations in either case.